# Simple isEven function throws syntax error

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why this function code will not run? Here is my code.

```
function isEven(n) {
    if (n%2 == 0) {
        return true;
    };
    else {
        return false;
    };
};
console.log(isEven(50));
```

I am getting an error message with the "else" statement.

Comment: The semicolon before the else has no place being there … Btw., next time please tgat your question properly, including one indicating the language you are using.

Comment: `var isEven = function(n) { return n%2 == 0; };`

Answer (score 2):

Bit handy on the semi-colons

Should be

```
function isEven(n) {
    if (n%2 == 0) {
       return true;
    }
    else { 
       return false;
    }
}
console.log(isEven(50));
```

Could even use

```
function isEven(n) {
    return (n%2 == 0);
}
console.log(isEven(50));
```

Comment: There are still two semicolons that has no reason to be there.